# Struggling with maths... How to reverse calculate a percentage?

Tags: php, math, percentage

I believe this is a language agnostic question and more focused on math, however I prefer PHP. I know how to calculate percentages the normal (forward) way:

```
$percent = 45.85;
$x = 2000000;
$deduction = ($percent / 100) * $x; // 917,000
$result = $x - $deduction; // 1,083,000
```

What I would like to do, is be able to reverse the calculation (assuming I only know the `$percent` and `$result`), for example...

54.15% of x = 1,083,000

How do I calculate x? I know the answer is 2,000,000, but how do I program it to arrive at that answer?

I found a [similar question & solution](http://www.answers.com/Q/20_percent_of_x_equals_60._How_do_you_calculate_x) through Google but I just don't understand how to implement it...

Comment: This is math, not programming.

Comment: @MacroMan I understand that, hence the title and first sentence. Are math questions not allowed?

Comment: probably best asked as a question on meta, but I wouldn't class this as a programming problem - wether it's _allowed_ of course is not up to me but I would say it's off topic for this site, particularly as there is a math site. In summary of you're asking "how do I do _____ in PHP?" then that's on-topic. If you're asking how to reverse a calculation _in general_ then it's not a programming question and therefore off-topic. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question of arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
1,083,000 * 100 / 54.15
```

In PHP, it will be

```
$x = $result * 100 / $percent
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say 54.15% of x = 1083000, you mean 0.5415 * x = 1083000. To solve for x, divide 0.5415 from both sides: x = 1083000 / 0.5415. The PHP is:

```
$p = 54.15;
$r = 108300;
// First, make p a number, not a percent
$p = $p/100; // I would actually use $p/= 100;
// Now, solve for x
$x = $r/$p;
```